# Editing a row of data in a table using an id

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am stuck with finding a means of being able to edit a specific row in my table. I have so far managed to come up with add,delete and search for a specific item that is stored in my database, i base the delete on a id field. Currently i am using PHP and HTML, could someone please show me a simple example that retrieves data from a database which stores in a table and when a user selects edit. The row that has been selected for edit becomes editable and thereafter updated without duplicating the data.

> **CLARIFICATION OF My QUESTION**

For Editing to work the UI must look like, when the edit button corresponding to particular row is clicked then all the columns with the data should get replaced with text boxes, i.e. row-wise edit form...

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to program this yourself, or can you just use a CMS? http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/try.php This might also be of interest: http://www.phpscaffold.com/

Comment: can you show the code of edit section that you used in your site ?

Comment: If you've figured out how to delete with an id, updating using an id should be no problem. What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Do you actually need anything besides the UPDATE syntax? You stated you can add, retrieve, and delete records. To update you just need to use an update sql query: `UPDATE <tablename> SET col1=newVal1, col2=newVal2 WHERE id=1;`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question, involves a lot of things. Not, just `php`, `mysql` or `html` but mainly `javascript`. However I will give a simple example, since you must already be able to bring the data onto a table.

Suppose your `<tr>` structure is similar to this

```
<tr>
<td class="nameField"><span class="text">My name</span></td>
<td class="controls"><a class="edit">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

Now using jQuery for this

```
$('a.edit').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td").not(".controls").each(function(k,v) {
                       // ^ find all td but not the one with the controls
        var span = $(this).children('span');
        //get the elem holding the value

        $(this).append('<input type="text" value="'+span.text()+'" />');
        // Add a text box with the input inside the td
        span.hide();
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/2zUtS/)

Comment: that is literally what i need but i was wondering would this update the database?

Comment: @Tesh, As you are new around here. You should read our [faq] to see how things go around there. :)

Comment: @Tesh, My example only shows how you can get your table data to change into input boxes. There are many things to be done in order for it to be saved. But this is another question, so you should ask another question for this.

Comment: @starx yeah im a new around here. I attempted to import some php in the tags [php][/php] but that didnt work out right. How would you go about doing this i was told to use the UPDATE function. I like the way the javascript that you created works but i would like it to be more on the permanent basis so it updates the database as well..

Comment: @Tesh, Just like the way i appended `<input>` boxes to the row, append a submit button too, then track the submit to update to the database. But really, this is another question. And you dont need to use [php]tags to bring the php, just paste the php, select them and press `ctrl+K` its a shortcut to enable the code display.

Comment: @Tesh As Starx said, You must ask a different question for getting the solution for using backend script for updating the value.. for this you will be showing the code you have implemented till now (given my Starx) and your requirement in the script, that will not only grab the users attention quickly to answer you but also you will earn some good points on it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Syntax you are looking for is [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

For example you have an articles table tied to a user with user_id, then you have a list of articles whereby users can select to edit (with edit link or something similar)

Then you'd do something like

`mysql_query('UPDATE articles set content = $new_content where id = $article_id');`

Don't forget to sanitize `$new_content` and `$article_id`, or better yet, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) altogether.

Comment: Please see the Updated clarification of question, he is not concerned about only the update query but he is also talking about the front end view

Comment: im looking for both front end and back end update. So for instance when the user selects edit it does the above and then once editing has been achieved, It updates the database.